# Mach-Zehnder interferometer vs Michelson interferometer

Tags: experimental-physics, interferometry

I am doing a project that is based on the Mach-Zehnder interferometer, and we're asked to compare the interferometer with Michelson's interferometer. I know the geometrical differences between the two, but when I think about it, I can't figure out when one is more suitable than the other. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct consequence of their respective geometries, I believe that the main difference between the Michelson and Mach-Zehnder interferometers is that the latter can be used to probe a sample with light only passing a single time through it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the difference between two,is that while in case of Michelson single output is obtained while in later two images are obtained with a phase of π.

This makes the mach zehnder interferometer more accurate in comparison to other